# Image mean subtraction on memmap array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, machine-learning, numpy-memmap

I have memmap array contains images like this where each image is an array of size (1,784) :

```
np.memmap('/home/usr/ds', dtype='float32', mode='r', shape=(1300, 784))
```

I want to know how can I do *Image mean subtraction* to normalize all images.

Comment: If you have OpenCV you can try `cv2.mean(image)`

Comment: I can't use OpenCV and normalize each image one by one. I wanted to normalize whole dataset in each eopch of training and test on the fly. Right now I'm using 
    mean_ds=np.mean(train_labeled)
    std_ds = np.std(train_labeled)
    train_labeled = (train_labeled - mean_ds) / std_ds
but it's not working!

Comment: **First** run `np.mean()` and `np.std()` for the entire dataset. **After that** perform *mean subtraction* for the dataset using the *mean* and *standard deviation* values.